# how to write validation in ajax php my sql

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

this is my code run but how to write validation code in this js
and i am using ajax php

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('#myForm').on('submit',function(e) {

    $.ajax({
    url:'toAction.php',
    data:$(this).serialize(),
    type:'POST',
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    $("#success").show().fadeOut(5000);
    },
    error:function(data){
        $("#error").show().fadeOut(5000);
    }
    });
e.preventDefault();
 });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this like

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myForm').on('submit',function(e) {
        if(OPRID==null || OPRID=="")
        { 
            alert("Operator Id must be filled out"); 
            return false; 
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
            url:'toAction.php',
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            type:'POST',
            success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $("#success").show().fadeOut(5000);
            },
            error:function(data){
            $("#error").show().fadeOut(5000);
            }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What kind of Validation you want

Comment: if (OPRID==null || OPRID=="")
    {
        alert("Operator Id must be filled out");
        return false;
    } 

 this

Comment: i am using your updated code its run but no show alert

Comment: What is the value of OPRID? Where it is coming? You have to fetch the value of this as well.Use this $('#YourInputFieldId').val(); Just before if condition.